# How to make the total correct according the selected checkboxes

Tags: php, html, checkbox

The problem is that the first value of the first items is the only one getting read and the second value is not and then the Total price is not exact as the selected item. We were so confused on what would be causing the incorrect total price and why is the first value is the only one being read even though the second value is flash in the website but not read as it is being increment and used in the function.
Here's the code of the said problem:

```
<script>
    function totalSum() {
        var price = document.getElementById("price");
        var food = document.getElementsByName("foodSelection");
        var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
        var totalValue = document.getElementsByName("total");
        var total = 0;
        var multiply = 0;
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
            if (food[i].checked) {
                // sum = parseInt(food[i].value) + parseInt(price.value);
                sum += parseInt(price.value);
                multiply = sum * parseInt(quantity.value);
                total += multiply;
                // total += parseInt(price.value);
            }
            quantity.value = parseInt(quantity.value);
            totalValue[0].value = total.toFixed(2) + "php";
        }
    }
</script>

<div class = "food-recommendations">
    <h2>Food Recommendations</h2>

    <table class = "food-recommendation-table">
        
        <tr>
            <th colspan ="3" style = "text-align: right;">Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    <?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM foods";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            
            // $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $name = $row['name'];
                $descrip = $row['foodDesc'];
                $pic = $row['pic'];
                $price = $row['price'];
                $foodID = $row['foodID'];
                $quanty = $row['quantity']; ?>
            <?php echo '<tr><td valign = "center"><input name = "foodSelection" type="checkbox"  value = "'. $foodID .'"
                            onclick="totalSum()"></td>
                        <td><img src = "../admin/foods/img/'. $pic .'" height = "200px" width = "300px" 
                        style = "border-radius: 30px;"></td>
                        <td><h3>'. $name . '</h3></td>
                        <td><p align = "center"><input type = "text" name="price" id = "price"  onblur = "totalSum()" value = "'.$price.'" style = "border:none; background: transparent;" hidden>₱'. $price .'</p></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" min="1" onclick="totalSum()" value = "'.$quanty.'"></td>
                        <td><p class = "accomp-text">'. $descrip .'</p></td></tr>
                        ';
                        ?>
    
            <?php }?>
        <tr>
            <th colspan = "5" style = "text-align: right;">TOTAL</th>
            <th><input type="text" name="total" id="total" value="0.00php" onclick = "totalSum()" readonly></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet. And don't add same id to all elements of 'price','quantity' and etc. in your 'tr' tags. best thing is to remove id attribute. if you really need it generate unique ids dynamically.
You have only used first element for the calulartion. that's why you got only the first's total.

```
function totalSum() {
     var price = document.getElementById("price");
     var food = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="foodSelection"]:checked');
     var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
     var totalValue = document.getElementsByName("total");
     var total = 0;
     var sum = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
       var multiply = 0;
       var closestTr = food[i].closest("tr");
       var rowPrice = closestTr.querySelector('input[name="price"]')[0];
       var rowQty = closestTr.querySelector('input[name="quantity"]')[0];

       rowPriceValue = parseInt(rowPrice.value);
       rowQtyValue = parseInt(rowQty.value);

       sum += parseInt(rowPriceValue);
       multiply = sum * rowQtyValue ;
       total += multiply;
     }
          
 totalValue[0].value = total.toFixed(2) + "php";                      
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, I am using visual studio for the program. What could be the whole code for this that you could come up with? The continuation of your snippet. Can you pls refer to my code? Because I am new to the keywords that you've used.

Comment: I just changed the your 'totalSum' function in the <script> tag. IDE doesn't matter for this code. If replacing this with your function doesn't work , please check there are any errors printed in the console. Share those if any. then I can help you to solve that out. Btw, what are the keywords that you don't understand?